system() returns the error sh: 1: : not found when I try to execute it with "/bin/sh" in the register rdi
I am following a walkthrough of a box on VulnHub, The Planets: Venus.
I got the shell to run through a buffer overflow, by putting an 8 byte padding, a gadget(pop rdi; ret), an address pointing to "/bin/sh", and the address of system() on the stack.
The problem occurred when I sent "/bin/sh" in the payload, before all the other payloads, and tried to execute system() with that address in rdi.
Breakpoint 2.1, __libc_system (line=0x7ffff7dcb42f "/bin/sh") at ../sysdeps/posix/system.c:202
202     in ../sysdeps/posix/system.c
(gdb) i r
rax            0x1                 1
rbx            0x7fffffffdae8      140737488345832
rcx            0x7ffff7d1c574      140737351107956
rdx            0x0                 0
rsi            0x4052a0            4215456
rdi            0x7ffff7dcb42f      140737351824431
rbp            0x0                 0x0
rsp            0x7fffffffd578      0x7fffffffd578
r8             0x0                 0
r9             0x0                 0
r10            0x0                 0
r11            0x202               514
r12            0x1                 1
r13            0x0                 0
r14            0x0                 0
r15            0x7ffff7ffd000      140737354125312
rip            0x7ffff7c58740      0x7ffff7c58740 <__libc_system>
eflags         0x202               [ IF ]
cs             0x33                51
ss             0x2b                43
ds             0x0                 0
es             0x0                 0
fs             0x0                 0
gs             0x0                 0
fs_base        0x7ffff7fa1740      140737353750336
gs_base        0x0                 0
(gdb) c
Continuing.
[Detaching after vfork from child process 26176]
$ exit

this is what happened when I used the string "/bin/sh" that was already in the code. You can see the shell executed.
Breakpoint 2.1, __libc_system (line=0x7fffffffd530 "/bin/sh") at ../sysdeps/posix/system.c:202
warning: 202    ../sysdeps/posix/system.c: No such file or directory
(gdb) i r
rax            0x1                 1
rbx            0x7fffffffdae8      140737488345832
rcx            0x7ffff7d1c574      140737351107956
rdx            0x0                 0
rsi            0x4052a0            4215456
rdi            0x7fffffffd530      140737488344368
rbp            0x0                 0x0
rsp            0x7fffffffd578      0x7fffffffd578
r8             0x0                 0
r9             0x0                 0
r10            0x0                 0
r11            0x202               514
r12            0x1                 1
r13            0x0                 0
r14            0x0                 0
r15            0x7ffff7ffd000      140737354125312
rip            0x7ffff7c58740      0x7ffff7c58740 <__libc_system>
eflags         0x202               [ IF ]
cs             0x33                51
ss             0x2b                43
ds             0x0                 0
es             0x0                 0
fs             0x0                 0
gs             0x0                 0
fs_base        0x7ffff7fa1740      140737353750336
gs_base        0x0                 0
(gdb) c
Continuing.
[Detaching after vfork from child process 26188]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

this is what happened when I used the address of "/bin/sh" in the payload. Every value in the registers are the same, except rdi, which point to different addresses, but they both have the same string inside. For some reason, this time it doesn't do anything and just segfaults right away.
execve("./venus_messaging", ["./venus_messaging"], 0x7fffffffdb40 /* 74 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x405000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff7fbd000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=100487, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 100487, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7ffff7fa4000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220\243\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2125328, ...}) = 0
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
mmap(NULL, 2170256, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ffff7c00000
mmap(0x7ffff7c28000, 1605632, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x28000) = 0x7ffff7c28000
mmap(0x7ffff7db0000, 323584, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b0000) = 0x7ffff7db0000
mmap(0x7ffff7dff000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1fe000) = 0x7ffff7dff000
mmap(0x7ffff7e05000, 52624, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff7e05000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff7fa1000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7ffff7fa1740) = 0
set_tid_address(0x7ffff7fa1a10)         = 27271
set_robust_list(0x7ffff7fa1a20, 24)     = 0
rseq(0x7ffff7fa2060, 0x20, 0, 0x53053053) = 0
mprotect(0x7ffff7dff000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x403000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7ffff7ffb000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
munmap(0x7ffff7fa4000, 100487)          = 0
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, [1], 4) = 0
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(9080), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
listen(3, 3)                            = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0), ...}) = 0
getrandom("\x7d\xf5\xd8\xd7\xab\x38\xab\x28", 8, GRND_NONBLOCK) = 8
brk(NULL)                               = 0x405000
brk(0x426000)                           = 0x426000
write(1, "Listening on port 9080\n", 23Listening on port 9080
) = 23
accept(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(51520), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 4
getpeername(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(51520), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
write(1, "Accepted connection from 127.0.0"..., 35Accepted connection from 127.0.0.1
) = 35
sendto(4, "Welcome to the Venus messaging s"..., 80, 0, NULL, 0) = 80
recvfrom(4, "loveandbeauty\n", 1024, 0, NULL, NULL) = 14
sendto(4, "Access granted, you can now send"..., 108, 0, NULL, 0) = 108
write(1, "User authenticated.\n", 20User authenticated.
)   = 20
recvfrom(4, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 2048, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1081
write(1, "Message received:\n", 18Message received:
)     = 18
write(1, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
sendto(4, "Message sent to the Venus space "..., 56, 0, NULL, 0) = 56
write(1, "Message acknowledgement sent.\n", 30Message acknowledgement sent.
) = 30
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7ffff7c45320}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7ffff7c45320}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
mmap(NULL, 36864, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff7fb4000
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[], [CHLD], 8) = 0
clone3({flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_VFORK|CLONE_CLEAR_SIGHAND, exit_signal=SIGCHLD, stack=0x7ffff7fb4000, stack_size=0x9000}, 88) = 27284
munmap(0x7ffff7fb4000, 36864)           = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [CHLD], NULL, 8) = 0
wait4(27284, $ exit
[{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 27284
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7ffff7c45320}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7ffff7c45320}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=27284, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x7974756100} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

this is the strace of using the string in the code.
execve("./venus_messaging", ["./venus_messaging"], 0x7fffffffdb40 /* 74 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x405000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff7fbd000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=100487, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 100487, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7ffff7fa4000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220\243\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2125328, ...}) = 0
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
mmap(NULL, 2170256, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ffff7c00000
mmap(0x7ffff7c28000, 1605632, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x28000) = 0x7ffff7c28000
mmap(0x7ffff7db0000, 323584, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b0000) = 0x7ffff7db0000
mmap(0x7ffff7dff000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1fe000) = 0x7ffff7dff000
mmap(0x7ffff7e05000, 52624, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff7e05000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff7fa1000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7ffff7fa1740) = 0
set_tid_address(0x7ffff7fa1a10)         = 27492
set_robust_list(0x7ffff7fa1a20, 24)     = 0
rseq(0x7ffff7fa2060, 0x20, 0, 0x53053053) = 0
mprotect(0x7ffff7dff000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x403000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7ffff7ffb000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
munmap(0x7ffff7fa4000, 100487)          = 0
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, [1], 4) = 0
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(9080), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
listen(3, 3)                            = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0), ...}) = 0
getrandom("\x3d\x1f\x1d\x36\x81\xf1\x5e\x11", 8, GRND_NONBLOCK) = 8
brk(NULL)                               = 0x405000
brk(0x426000)                           = 0x426000
write(1, "Listening on port 9080\n", 23Listening on port 9080
) = 23
accept(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(33584), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 4
getpeername(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(33584), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
write(1, "Accepted connection from 127.0.0"..., 35Accepted connection from 127.0.0.1
) = 35
sendto(4, "Welcome to the Venus messaging s"..., 80, 0, NULL, 0) = 80
recvfrom(4, "loveandbeauty\n", 1024, 0, NULL, NULL) = 14
sendto(4, "Access granted, you can now send"..., 108, 0, NULL, 0) = 108
write(1, "User authenticated.\n", 20User authenticated.
)   = 20
recvfrom(4, "\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2"..., 2048, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1081
write(1, "Message received:\n", 18Message received:
)     = 18
write(1, "\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2"..., 1024/bin/sh
) = 1024
sendto(4, "Message sent to the Venus space "..., 56, 0, NULL, 0) = 56
write(1, "Message acknowledgement sent.\n", 30Message acknowledgement sent.
) = 30
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7ffff7c45320}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7ffff7c45320}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
mmap(NULL, 36864, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff7fb4000
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[], [CHLD], 8) = 0
clone3({flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_VFORK|CLONE_CLEAR_SIGHAND, exit_signal=SIGCHLD, stack=0x7ffff7fb4000, stack_size=0x9000}, 88) = 27496
munmap(0x7ffff7fb4000, 36864)           = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [CHLD], NULL, 8) = 0
wait4(27496, sh: 1: : not found
[{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 127}], 0, NULL) = 27496
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7ffff7c45320}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7ffff7c45320}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=27496, si_uid=1000, si_status=127, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x7974756100} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

9 lines from the bottom, you can see the error sh: 1: : not found instead of the shell executing like it did when I used the string that was in the code.
The only difference between the two cases is where the string "/bin/sh" is. Why is this causing a problem?
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!
